# Compiling and building new SRF

Tags: siebel

I do not know anything in Siebel. But we have a requirement that I need to comment one line of code in one of the applet scripts and build a new SRF. What is the procedure? I am using Siebel 6 and I have access to Siebel tools.

Also let me know any useful sites for help on Siebel 6.

Answer (score 3):

You should have your local repository connected to a server repository so you can check out and check in your changes to the server repository.  If you are not worried about check outs and check ins then you can do the following.  Otherwise you have environment setup steps to perform before commenting out the code.

If you know the applet where the script is located, then search and right click that applet in Siebel Tools.  Select Edit Server Scripts (if not there then choose the option Edit Browser Scripts).  Find the line of code and prefix with `//.`  Ctrl S to save the changes.  That line of code should turn green.

Now the changes are in your local repository.  You should put a SRF file from your server environment on your local machine.  Right click your applet and select Compile Selected Objects and choose the file that you copied to your local machine.

Now your change has been compiled into the SRF that originated from the server and is ready to be deployed to your server for testing.  You will have to shutdown, move the srf, and restart siebel services before being able to test your changes.